# Word for Mac: how to increase/decrease font size with (laptop) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, font, display

Again, title says it all.

On a normal Mac keyboard, shortcuts for font increase/decrease are:

SHIFT CMD < - decrease
SHIFT CMD > - increase

However, on a laptop keyboard the latter doesn't work. I just can't reach the ">" key while CMD pressed. Turn on the keyboard viewer and see for yourself.

I press SHIFT, the "<" turns to ">", so far so good... but once i press CMD (while still holding SHIFT), it goes back to "<" so I can only decrease font size, but not increase.

These shortcuts are speeding up the workflow tremendously, I wan't 'em! :-)

Any suggestions? Thanx...

Comment: What language keyboard are you using?

Comment: Seems you cant actually customize microsoft word in OSx. This is quite brutal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer. You can assign keyboard shortcuts to any Word 2011 command. Go to Tools, then Customize Keyboard. Choose Format category. Find GrowFont and assign a keyboard shortcut to it. Find ShrinkFont and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

I assigned CMD+SHIFT+Arrow keys (up to grow, down to shrink).

They make no conflicts to me, and they are Word only.

These two single keyboard shortcuts make worlds of difference when editing docs.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Word for Mac 2019 now has built-in shortcuts for this:

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> increases the font size by one step

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> decreases the font size by one step

Comment: Yes, these work in 2019, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> increases the font size by one point.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> decreases the font size by one point.

Answer (score 0):

- Increase the font size: <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>
- Decrease the font size: <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: CMD+ "+" changes to superscript, are you using custom shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Quite often this type of command, using keys with *punctuation* rather than just letters, is language-dependant.
Also, quite often, the physical key is in the same place as it would be in English, making the actual keystroke generated different.

Here are common examples of key-stroke *types* where the generated character changes, but the position remains the same.

[image]

These are common pairing positions for many key command 'sets'. It's recommended if you are using a non-English language you try these positions on your own keyboard, ignoring the actual characters printed on them.

The two on the left are different in **ANSI** [US] & **ISO** [UK English & variants for rest of the world]

Answer (score -1):

Increase the font size : COMMAND + SHIFT + >

Decrease the font size : COMMAND + SHIFT + <

Comment: This is exactly what the OP said didn't work.

Comment: Its working for me. You can refer: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Word-keyboard-shortcuts-c0ca851f-3d58-4ce0-9867-799df73666a7

Comment: 'Working for me' really doesn't help the OP at all. It adds nothing.

Comment: This worked fine on my 2012 Macbook Pro with Word 15.33.

Comment: Now in Word 2019 you go to Tools - Customize Keyboard i assign whatever you want. It's no big deal any more :-)